# Why will turning options on and off not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class SettingsScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Muzica;
    public GameObject Oftat;
    public GameObject SFX;
    public GameObject Fullscreen;
    public GameObject VolumObject;
    public bool MuzicaBool = true;
    public bool OftatBool;
    public bool SFXBool = true;
    public bool FullscreenBool = true;
    public float VolumFloat = 1f;
    public AudioSource on;
    public AudioSource off;
    public static SettingsScript instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(MuzicaBool + " " + OftatBool + " " + SFXBool + " " + FullscreenBool + " " + VolumFloat);
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Meniu");
    }

    public void Volum()
    {
        AudioListener.volume = VolumFloat;
    }

    public void MuzicaOn()
    {
        if (MuzicaBool)
        {
            Muzica.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0);
            MuzicaBool = !MuzicaBool;
        }
        else
        {
            Muzica.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
        MuzicaBool = !MuzicaBool;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Muzica");
        if(MuzicaBool)
        {
            on.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            off.Play();
        }
    }

    public void OftatOn()
    {
        if (OftatBool)
        {
            Oftat.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Oftat.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
        OftatBool = !OftatBool;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Oftat");
        if(OftatBool)
        {
            on.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            off.Play();
        }
    }

    public void SFXOn()
    {
        if (SFXBool)
        {
            SFX.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            SFX.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
        SFXBool = !SFXBool;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("SFX");
        if(SFXBool)
        {
            on.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            off.Play();
        }
    }

    public void FullscreenOn()
    {
        if (FullscreenBool)
        {
            Fullscreen.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Fullscreen.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }
        FullscreenBool = !FullscreenBool;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Fullscreen");
        if(FullscreenBool)
        {
            on.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            off.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

here's a video of the menu, not working

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfNOi86lbxI&ab_channel=GhiocelGames

The option for music "Muzică", does not turn off.

The other options do not respect the boolean variables used in the code, and at first wont turn off if on, as you can see in the video

I want to make settings for my game.

Comment: Btw in general you should rather use **one single** `AudioSource`, two `AudioClips` and then rather use e.g. `audioSource.PlayOneShot(onClip);`

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I see between your bools is you are instantly turning the musicabool to false right after putting it to true, while the other bools don't have that line of code, could it explain your issue?
The line: "musicabool = !musicabool"

Comment: I think you've spotted the issue correctly but there's a bit more guidance needed.
MuzicaBool = !MuzicaBool; line occurs twice in the code and OP needs to know or decide which one is the problem.
I can see a way to make it work by removing either one...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, by replacing the dumb color things with setactive and doing some tweaks

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer so it's more clear? Which code has been replaced with what, which tweaks did you do? Other's might have a similar problem and your details could help them.

Comment: just replaced the color things for SetActive() and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class SettingsScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Muzica, Oftat, SFX, Fullscreen, VolumObject;
    public bool MuzicaBool = true, OftatBool, SFXBool = true, FullscreenBool = true;
    public float VolumFloat = 1f;
    public AudioSource on, off;
    public static SettingsScript instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;

        //You can put the code for
        //loading the save here
        //(You can use PlayerPrefs)

        //Set objects' states to their values. (Fixes the problem where the toggles don't change)
        Muzica.SetActive(MuzicaBool);
        Oftat.SetActive(OftatBool);
        SFX.SetActive(SFXBool);
        Fullscreen.SetActive(FullscreenBool);
        AudioListener.volume = VolumFloat;
        
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(MuzicaBool + " " + OftatBool + " " + SFXBool + " " + FullscreenBool + " " + VolumFloat);
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Meniu");
    }

    public void Volum()
    {
        AudioListener.volume = VolumFloat;
    }

    public void MuzicaOn()
    {
        MuzicaBool = !MuzicaBool;
        Muzica.SetActive(MuzicaBool);
        PlaySound(MuzicaBool);

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Muzica");
    }

    public void OftatOn()
    {
        OftatBool = !OftatBool;
        Oftat.SetActive(OftatBool);
        PlaySound(OftatBool);

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Oftat");
    }

    public void SFXOn()
    {
        SFXBool = !SFXBool;
        SFX.SetActive(SFXBool);
        PlaySound(SFXBool);

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("SFX");
    }

    public void FullscreenOn()
    {
        FullscreenBool = !FullscreenBool;
        Fullscreen.SetActive(FullscreenBool);
        PlaySound(FullscreenBool);

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Fullscreen");
    }
    
    //A method to play the 'on' or 'off' sound
    void PlaySound(bool onBool)
    {
        if(onBool)
            on.Play();
        else
            off.Play();
    }
}
```

I've also made some 'optimisations' but I'm not an expert or anything so feel free to correct me lol

Comment: Could you specifically point out what was the relevant change to fix OP's issue? ;)